# Reboot after clicking on movies on Netflix only

Tags: windows-10, video, reboot, netflix, xdebug

This problem happens only on Netflix, not on any other video viewing site. After clicking on a movie, I get blue screen with stopcode message and page fault in nonpaged area. Message says wait while they collect data, then my computer reboots and restarts. I have updated all drivers. Using Windows 10 os, On Edge and Internet Explorer browsers.
 I've used Edge browser for several years to view movies on Netflix before this problem happened. I can click on and view videos on all other sites without this happening.

Comment: Does this issue occur with other browsers?

Comment: I've tried it using only Edge and Internet Explorer. I don't have any others downloaded into my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know this particular problem. However, as a Sys Admin, I have seen similar problems with various pieces of software on Windows before.

I do not know your experience with windows, so I will take a middle of the road approach. Feel free to as for clarification if you need to.

The Blue Screen of Death means that some piece of memory, somewhere, has been corrupted or over written and the OS no longer knows what it is supposed to be doing. The reboot means that it can't fix itself, so it needs to restart.

If Edge *used* to work, and it doesn't anymore, that generally means that a software update caused the problem *Any* software. Edge, Security Fixes, Java, Drivers, etc. It is tough to tell exactly what.

First, I would look through my BIOS setup and see if there is a test option. Test all of the memory -- maybe you have a memory card going bad.
Then scan the hard disk for bad sectors. Maybe a memory swap to disk is causing the issue.
Clean up any old files on your hard drive. While many, many folks will argue with me, experience has shown that your windows operating disk (usually drive C) needs to be 1/3 to 1/2 free space or windows will have "weird" issues.

Second, try another browser. Chrome, Mozilla, etc. If you load another browser, and you have the same issue, then it is NOT an issue with your browser and you can uninstall it if you wish.

Third, if possible, uninstall and re-install whatever software you are using. The uninstall option may have a "Repair/Reload" option.

Fourth, look for a restore point from a time before you had the issue (and turn off automatic updates for this test). Try Netflix again. If it works, then a software update broke it. Then you have to manually update your apps one at a time to see what broke it.

Good Luck!

Comment: A quick internet search shows that this is a known issue. I found 2 more possibilities.<br>Your hardware could be overheating. Clean the computer. If you don't know how to do this, best to have a professional do it.<br>
Here's a link to a possible solution:
https://windowsreport.com/netflix-problems-windows-10/

Comment: I think my problem may be Microsoft Silverlight feature. I don't have it installed in my computer, and I read on a search that Edge browser doesn't support it. Microsoft had a big update last year for Silverlight, and a computer has to have it in order to view videos on Netflix. Prior to this update viewing videos on Netflix was possible, because a different frame (other than Silverlight) was used. I'm in the process of installing a different browser that supports Silverlight, and will install Silverlight. Does anyone know about this?

Comment: Cyberlink Media Center also deactivated around the same time I could no longer view videos on Netflix. Windows 10 no longer supports them or they don't support Windows 10. This is another consideration for my problem. Some components that enabled Netflix videos to be viewed could have been deactivated. I know for sure that dvd discs played from tray on my computer could no longer play with Cyberlink, so I downloaded another player software, which plays them.

Comment: I have never had an issue with reboots, but I do have to use Opera to view Netflix on my PC (I have other browsers which do not work for varying reasons, though Silverlight is a big one as far as I'm aware).